Electric Potential simple questions

The upper problem is from Griffiths Electrodynamics book.
Answer is in the Answer (a).
This is a simple question, because with equation 2.27, it is just adding all the positive charge potential.
But my question is what if the right charge is a negative charge? Then it would be a negative potential. So adding the two potentials would give zero, as I drew in the picture with a pencil.
But if $P$ has a charge (positive), then it would be moved in the direction of the green arrow.
How can charge $P$ move even though it has zero potential? A charge moves from higher to lower potential.
But P has zero potential, what is the force that moves P charge?


How can a P charge can move even though it has zero potential?

Because the force is not determined by the value of the potential. The force is determined by the slope of the potential.

Because a charge moves from higher to lower potential.

Yes, so you need to calculate the potential at two points and see which is higher. One point is right on the line you drew. The next point is slightly off the line you drew at a location displaced by $\delta x$. Calculate the potential difference between those two points and divide by $\delta x$. That gives the force.

You're right; the potential at point $P,$ due to one positive charge and one negative charge, does sum to zero. But the positive charge $q_P$ at $P$ still feels a force, despite the potential at the point being zero.
Electrical potential here is a scalar quantity - the sum of potentials from all nearby charges; the potential energy per unit charge at that point.
But the electric field is a vector quantity derived from the spatial variation of the potential, namely the gradient of the potential.
What we need to know is that zero potential does not mean zero electric field.  That is, a charge can still feel a force even though the electric potential is zero at that position. But the electric field, being the gradient of the potential, depends on how the potential changes around the point - not just its value at that point.
So there can still be a non-zero electric field at $P$ due to the charge distribution. And the force on a positive charge at $P$ comes from the electric field in that location; not electric potential:
$$\textbf{F} = q_P \textbf{E}.$$
Here $q_P$ is the charge at $P$ and $\textbf{E}$ the electric field there.
So in your case, the potential might be zero since the charges cancel each other out, but the two fields point in the same direction. Hence, their magnitudes add up.
The charge at $P$ moves because the electric field causes it to experience a force at that point, not because of the potential value at that point.

But if $P$ has a charge (positive), then it would be moved in the direction of the green arrow.
If an external force was applied the test charge at $P$ whose magnitude was the same as $\vec F$ and was opposite in direction and the test charge was moved down that external force $-\vec F$ would do no work as its displacement would be perpendicular to its direction.
